# Problems routing with JSON

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm working with `JSON`. But apparently I'm doing something wrong with my calls, because I'm not getting into the `GetJSON_Register` inside the `AccountController`. I'm no expert in `Javascript` at all, but I think it's a routing problem in my script.

As I said I'm not very good with `Javascript` so I'm just going to post all of my functions:

**Register.cshtml**

```
<form action="" method="post" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="email" id="register-email" placeholder="Enter email" value="" required="required" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="password" id="register-password" placeholder="Enter password" value="" required="required" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="repeatPassword">Repeat Password</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="password" id="register-repeatPassword" placeholder="Repeat password" value="" required="required" />
    </div>

    <hr />

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="firstname">Firstname</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="register-firstname" placeholder="Enter firstname" value="" required="required" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="lastname">Lastname</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="register-lastname" placeholder="Enter lastname" value="" required="required" />
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="register-btn">Register</button>

    <div id="message-register">
        <span></span>
    </div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#register-btn').click(function () {
            registera();
        });
    });

    function registera() {
        var $email = $('#register-email'),
            $password = $('#register-password'),
            $firstname = $('#register-firstname'),
            $lastname = $('#register-lastname'),
            $message = $('#message-register.span');

        $message.className = 'alert';
        showLoadingText($message);

        register($email, $password, $firstname, $lastname, function(data) {
            if (data.IsValid) {
                $message.html('');
                $message.className = '';
            } else {
                $message.className = 'alert alert-danger';
                $message.html(data.Message);
            }
        });
    };    
</script>
```

**script.js**

```
function register(email, password, firstname, lastname) {
    $.getJSON("/Account/GetJson_Register", { email: email, password: password, firstname: firstname, lastname: lastname }, function (data) {
        return data;
    });
};
```

**AccountController.cs**

```
public ActionResult GetJSON_Register(string email, string password, string firstname, string lastname)
{
    string message = "";
    bool success = true;

    repository.Register(email, password, firstname, lastname);

    if(Error.Instance.Message != "")
    {
        message = Error.Instance.Message;
        success = false;
    }

    return Json(new { IsValid = success, Message = message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**EDIT**

Tried changing the

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="register-btn">Register</button>
```

into

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="register-btn" onclick="registera()" value="Register" />
```

and removed the `.click` event.

Now in my `Chrome Javascript Console` I get this message when clicking the button

```
 Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to read the 'selectionDirection' property from 'HTMLInputElement': The input element's type ('email') does not support selection. jquery-latest.min.js:4
     Vc jquery-latest.min.js:4
     Vc jquery-latest.min.js:4
     m.param jquery-latest.min.js:4
     m.extend.ajax jquery-latest.min.js:4
     m.(anonymous function) jquery-latest.min.js:4
     m.extend.getJSON jquery-latest.min.js:4
     register script.js:63
     registera Register:213
     onclick Register:180
GET http://localhost:1317/d61bfd81ee4f49eaae35adc38c5d9ea2/arterySignalR/ping?r…2Flocalhost%3A1317%2FAccount%2FRegister&browserName=Chrome&_=1411294396408 404 (Not Found) browserLink:37
    send browserLink:37
    p.extend.ajax browserLink:37
    i.transports._logic.pingServer browserLink:62
    (anonymous function) browserLink:62
```

Comment: Have you debugged your code? I do not see any specific wrong in your code. Check your chrome/IE console in case there are any errors, also do check if you have referenced all JS script files.

Comment: @ramiramilu: I've used the debug tool in VS and I never get into the GetJSON_Register method. Haven't however checked with the chrome browser tool to see where it's going

Comment: @ramiramilu: Debug with the js console in chrome, and got the message represented in the question, after I edited the button

Comment: Can you comment the complete code and make a simple alert of `$email` and see if you are getting proper value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution. It seems like I'm passing an `object` from my **Register.cshtml** to the `register` function in **script.js** which takes in a `value` not an `object`.

So the solution is to change in Register.cshtml

```
register($email, $password, $firstname, $lastname, function(data) {
        if (data.IsValid) {
            $message.html('');
            $message.className = '';
        } else {
            $message.className = 'alert alert-danger';
            $message.html(data.Message);
        }
    });
```

into

```
register($email.val, $password.val, $firstname.val, $lastname.val, function(data) {
        if (data.IsValid) {
            $message.html('');
            $message.className = '';
        } else {
            $message.className = 'alert alert-danger';
            $message.html(data.Message);
        }
    });
```